# How to make a specific file extension callable in DOSBox?

Tags: batch-file, command, dos, 16-bit, dosbox

For example if I type `hello.asm` on the screen,

I want a specific batch file to be called,

```
tasm %0
tlink %0
%0
```

Or something like command-regex or some utility....`*.asm.bat`

Comment: What version of DOS is being emulated?  Try `help doskey`.  If that doesn't work, try `doskey /?` instead.

Comment: Dosbox 0.74 Reported DOS version 5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DosKey has been around since MS-DOS 5.  I find it easiest to use with a macro file and a script to load that file.  But according to [DosBox](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Commands), they do not have support for DosKey.  You've already tried [Retro Software's Enhanced DosKey](http://retro.software/downloads/download/246-dos-enhancements/1408-enhanced-doskey-2-8) you can use that.

```
doskey /macrofile=YourMacroFile.txt
```

If you want your batch file to take the macrofile name as a parameter:

```
doskey /macrofile=%1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207803/discussion-on-answer-by-jwdonahue-how-to-make-a-specific-file-extension-callable).